# How can I align circle next a rectangle at same starting y-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to locate a circle next to a rectangle where their top line starts from same y-axis. When I try `node.170` it changes if a rectangle has multiple lines.

```
○ |--------|   ○ |--------|
  |  Node  |     |--------|
  |--------|
```

the basic code is as follow:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                                                                                                  \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,shapes.misc}
                                                                                                                                                                   \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[                                                                                                                                                   block/.style={rectangle,draw,text centered,outer sep=0pt,semithick},
    circ/.style = {circle,draw,blue,text centered,inner sep=1pt}                                                                                                       ]
    \node[block] (n1) {Node};                                                                                                                                          \node[circ,left=1.3mm of n1.170] {1};
                                                                                                                                                                       \node[block,right =of n1,text width=8mm] (n2) {Node Node};
    \node[circ,left=1.3mm of n2.170] {1};                                                                                                                          \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output is as follow:
[image]

wanted output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

**Edit:**
in definition of picture elements styles is now considered OP comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                                                                                                  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[  
node distance = 4.5mm and 12mm,  % <---   
 block/.style = {draw, semithick, align=center, inner sep=3pt},
  circ/.style = {circle, draw, blue, inner sep=1pt,
                 node distance =2pt and 7pt}  % 2pt = 3pt (of block) - 1pt (of circle)}
                    ]
\node[block,below] (n1) {Node};                                                                                                                                          \node[circ,below left=of n1.north west] {1};

\node[block,below] (n2) at (3,0) {Node\\ text};                                                                                                                                          \node[circ,below left=of n2.north west] {2};

\node[block,below=of n2] (n3) {Node};                                                                                                                                          \node[circ,below left=of n3.north west] {3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it produce

[image]

Comment: I forget to add but I was using `node distance = 4.5mm and 12mm,` for different objects, which has much greater value, can we define additional node distance for circle?

Comment: @alper, you can set node distance as you wish. if needed also locally in `circle` style definition. I just try  reproduce showed images, so please edit your question and provide more information,  what you after, maybe with code for more realistic scenario of your images.

Comment: @alper, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. Why did you use `below left=of` instead of `left=of`?

Comment: @alper, because I use `positioning` syntax do node placement. Between `below left=of... ` and `left=of  ...` is huge difference. First define distance between nodes borders, the second between their centers.